# Error while migrating form kafka to RAFT in Hyperledger fabirc

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric-ca, raft

I am migrating from kafka to raft, When I have changed state from "NORMAL" to "STATE_MAINTENANCE"  and created the final expected envelope as per the procedure.

Note: We are using BYFN script
HF version: **1.4.3**

My CLI pointed to Org1MSP, I signed config update transaction, later I changed CLI pointing to Org2MSP and signed, finally submitted the new channel config update to the orderer.After submission, getting a following error message.

Error on CLI: "`Error: got unexpected status: BAD_REQUEST -- error applying config update to existing channel 'mychannel': error authorizing update: error validating DeltaSet: policy for [Value]  /Channel/Orderer/ConsensusType not satisfied: implicit policy evaluation failed - 0 sub-policies were satisfied, but this policy requires 1 of the 'Admins' sub-policies to be satisfied`"

Orderer log: "`[channel: mychannel] Rejecting broadcast of config message from 172.21.0.13:51078 because of error: error applying config update to existing channel 'mychannel': error authorizing update: error validating DeltaSet: policy for [Value]  /Channel/Orderer/ConsensusType not satisfied: implicit policy evaluation failed - 0 sub-policies were satisfied, but this policy requires 1 of the 'Admins' sub-policies to be satisfied`"

Please let me know if I am doing something wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: By seeing the error logs it seems that it requires orderer identity. Try bootstraping your cli with an orderer information as it might need the OrdererMSP to sign off this update.

Comment: @Trinayan, Thank you for the reply, I tried with orderer MSP as well, but no luck, getting same error. I have checked the signature as well.

Answer (score 1):

By default, cryptogen tool generate orderer admin user certificate with OU as client for 1.4.3 fabric version.
For peer admin user, it generates certificate with OU as admin which is correct(expected). In case of orderer, its creating wrong OU(Organization Unit) as client. We need to add the following part  crypto-config.yaml in the orderer section.

```
CA:
  OrganizationalUnit: admin
```

Once you added above part, recreate certificate and check orderer certificate  OU as admin by following command

```
openssl x509 -in certificate.crt -text
```